# Не получается вынести reactjs из бандла

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Приятного дня. 
Решил я из бандла реакт и реакт дом повыносить. 
Взял библиотеки из https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.1.1
Добавил на страничку как

```
<script src="react.development.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

В конфиге веб-пака добавил

```
externals: {
  "react": "React"
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react/),
  …
```

Получил бандл без вебпака и ошибку в консоли:

```
main-678cde5fa082de577289.bundle.js:5443 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react"
```

Где я свернул не туда?

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Не делайте так,лучше
`entry: {
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
},
plugins: [
    new new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(options)
]`
```

Ссылка на плагин https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

Comment: new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react/), — был лишним, без него заработало. Но так не придется утягивать руками библиотеку, спасибо!